# using window type graphics in C programming

Tags: c, winapi

Hi I want to write a program in C. When I will run that program it should first show me a form (window) which takes x and y from user. Then I will enter the value of X and y and press "calculate" button that is on the user window(form). After I press "calculate" button the control of program should run following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;

    int x,y,z,sum;/*the value of x and y should be intered form user window*/
    fptr=fopen("newfile.txt","r");/*i have one file that contains a integer value*/

    fscanf(fptr,"%d",&z);
    sum=x+y+z;
    printf("the sum is %d",sum);
}
```

and at last it should show me the value of sum that is the sum of x y and z. if you have problem understanding my question please let me know....Thank you

PS:Actually I have the image of what the form or user window should look like...being the beginning user in stalkoverflow i couldn't post it in here so if you feel like watching that image i can send you that as well just tell me how should i send it to you.

Comment: You've shown C code that does nothing but read input from a text file and write a simple addition operation's result out to the console. Please put some effort into solving your own homework problem before asking here - you've done no research into using the Windows API to `CreateWindow` or `GetMessage` or `DrawText` the results to the window. (Hint: I've formatted as code some things you should search for in the process.) Once you've done some work in figuring out how to do it yourself, someone here can help you solve specific problems you run into during the process of doing the work.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for your reply . My actual problem was not what i have mentioned...actually its a part of project i'm dealing with. I tried to learn graphics of C language but it seemed quite hard for me. So i thought of getting some idea on it. If you have got some programming code that relates to my problem and if you can share i really appreciate that thank you...

Answer (score 0):

If GUI is not necessary, your program may run in console in windows. And you can write a .bat script to make it a little friendly. 
If GUI is must, consider to use MFC and pop up a message box to show the result.

Comment: Actually I dont need GUI for output ...I need it for input ...like to take name and location of my file that I'm going to use in program and to take some values that will be used in program.Thanks